# How do I style this code using html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

The code below is for listing blogger posts within a Label Name, if the post has the specific Label Name it will be shown in this list. I would like to be able to change the appearance of how everything is displayed by changing where the post image would look, and where the title would look, change background color, add borders, shadows change the font etc ...(I know how to change the appearance with css, but I do not know how to integrate the code below with css and html) At the moment the code shows the title and the right of the title the image.

```js
      var startIndex = 1;
      var maxResults = 5;
      var allResults = [];
      function sendQuery12()
      {
        var scpt = document.createElement("script");
        scpt.src = "https://levon-ltr.blogspot.com//feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&callback=processPostList12&start-index=" + startIndex + "&max-results=" + maxResults;
        document.body.appendChild(scpt);
      }
      function printArrayResults(root)
      { 
        //Sort Alphebetically
        allResults.sort(function(a, b){
          var a_string = a.children[0].textContent ;
          var b_string = b.children[0].textContent ;
          if(a_string < b_string) return -1;
          if(a_string > b_string) return 1;
          return 0;
        })
        var elmt = document.getElementById("postList12");
        for (index = 0; index < allResults.length; index++) {
          elmt.appendChild(allResults[index]);
        }
      }
      function processPostList12(root)
      {   
        var elmt = document.getElementById("postList12");
        if (!elmt)
          return;
        var feed = root.feed;
        if (feed.entry.length > 0)
        {
          for (var i = 0; i < feed.entry.length; i++)
          {
            var entry = feed.entry[i];
            var title = entry.title.$t;
            var date = entry.published.$t;

            if( entry.media$thumbnail != undefined ){
              var imageThumb = entry.media$thumbnail.url ;
            } else {
              var imageThumb = 'https://i.imgur.com/PqPqZQN.jpg' ;
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++)
            {
              if (entry.link[j].rel == "alternate")
              {
                var url = entry.link[j].href;
                if (url && url.length > 0 && title && title.length > 0)
                {
                  var liE = document.createElement("li");
                  var a1E = document.createElement("a");
                  var postImage = document.createElement("img");

                  a1E.href = url;
                  a1E.textContent = title;
                  postImage.src = imageThumb;

                  liE.appendChild(a1E);
                  liE.appendChild(postImage);

                  //elmt.appendChild(liE);
                  allResults.push(liE);

                }
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          if (feed.entry.length >= maxResults)
          {
            startIndex += maxResults;
            sendQuery12();
          } else {
            printArrayResults();
          }
        }
      }
      sendQuery12();
```

```html
    <div>
      <ul id="postList12"></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think this is something you should be learning on your own through pre-existing guides and tutorials. No harm in asking, it just may not be well-received.

Comment: I'm here to learn from people who know, I have a question, I do not know if it's possible, I come and I ask, Just like everyone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates stuff you can style with CSS. For example:

```
#postList12 li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Use the inspector in your browser to see what it makes. If you want to change the order of elements or add new ones you’ll have to edit the script to do that.